# I use a home network with DHCP enabled and I cant set a static ip

Tags: networking, router, lan, dhcp, ipv4

So I'm quite perplexed by this...
I used the basic technique of going to network and sharing center, going to ethernet properties selecting Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/ipv4) and selecting an ip address for myself which is in the range of IPs on my router page.

So I checked ipconfig and got [this](https://prnt.sc/t8e5d3) and [this](https://prnt.sc/t8e7lg) page and thought I was done,
but when I checked in game and also through another software it showed my computer's ip address to be `192.168.56.1` instead of `192.168.0.13`

Also my router has this [special page](http://prntscr.com/t8ec2e) that says it can set a static ip but didn't help

I'm using a Dlink DIR-825ACG1 as my home router

Comment: looks like you are either confusing your local NIC with a virtual box nic, or you are confused about how nat connections work in VBox. vbox NAT networks are on a seperate (virtual) network than you host lan network. if you want the virtualbox VM to operate on the same network as your host or other LAN hosts, use a bridged connection in vbox (edit the vm settings -> network interface) and it will pull an IP from your LAN DHCP server, and be accessible to all your lan hosts.

Comment: This worked! I deleted my VM application and it deleted the Virtual box nic